# Not able to enter the for loop in Testcafe

Tags: loops, for-loop, testcafe

I am new to testcafe and currently writing tests for a web application. The webpage has some radio-boxes consisting of radio buttons and web links of which only one is selected by default. I am trying to traverse through all the radio-boxes and identify the selected one. However, I noticed that my tests get executed successfully but don't seem to be entering the for loop. Could you please help to identify the issue? Below is the snippet and result.

Code result:

[image]

```
test('Test1', async t => {
    await t
          .maximizeWindow()
        //test actions to reach the radio-boxes
        
          //identifying the selected radio-box
        console.log("Before Loop");
            for (let serviceCount = 0; serviceCount < serviceOptions.count; serviceCount++) {
         console.log("Inside Loop");
                if ((await serviceOptions.nth(serviceCount).contains('months or km')) && checkboxRadiobutton.nth(serviceCount).checked) {
                console.log("pass");
                } else {
                console.log("fail");
            }
           
      //Open the link provided in the radio-box
            await t.click(serviceDetailsLink.nth(serviceCount));
  }
});
```

Comment: Can `serviceOptions.count` be zero or less? Log its value,

Comment: thank you so much, I got your hint and corrected it out, works fine now. cheers.